# Magnetic field due to current in a straight line

Tags: electromagnetism

In the derivation of a formula for magnetic field due to a current in a straight line, I have come the across the following,

[image]

Since we considered the current element to be at a distance $l$ from the foot of perpendicular from $P$, and we took the element to be $dl$, we were able to differentiate $l$ to get $dl$, but how/why is this allowed, the variable $l$ has been deliberately considered, I am confused as to how this can be done, how are $l$ and $dl$ related here? If $l$ was the length of the wire NM, it would've made sense since then $dl$ would be a small part of it.

Comment: $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dl$ does give you the length of the wire.

Comment: But the length of the wire is not $L$.

Comment: im assuming the wire is of fixed length, if not just replace the bounds by positive and negative infinity. i dont understand what your confusion is haha

Comment: My confusion is, why is element at a distance $l$ from the foot of perpendicular, $dl$?

Comment: Taking the limits $\theta_1\rightarrow 0,\theta_2\rightarrow \pi$ in equation (35.4) the magnetic field due to current in the infinite straight wire is : 
$$
B=\dfrac{\mu_0\,I}{2\pi\,d}
$$
The participation (35.4) of the finite line segment in the computation of this field is not a physical quantity and thus has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This touches on an important and  powerful strategy in physics, and it is why Newton invented Calculus.

If you have some variable $f(t,x)$ that changes over time or space, restricting yourself to an infinitesimal slice of time $dt$ or space $dx$ allows you to treat the variable as constant. Then you can write simple equations relating it to other things.

Since the field as a result of the whole wire changes over its length, and the fields at every point change, you can use differentials to relate a tiny slice of the wire $dl$ to a single point $P$ using their equation (i), and then integrate over the wire length or over space to get the desired quantity.

That being said, I believe your question is rooted in simple misunderstanding of the figure. $dl$ is a tiny slice of the wire, located at vertical distance $l$ from point $O$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my question is different, it is in the comments.

Comment: You asked how $l$ was differentiated to get $dl$.  It was not. Rather $dl$ is simply a tiny change in $l$.  Just like $\Delta l$, except extremely small

Comment: Yes, it was differentiated, look to the bottom of the pic.

Comment: Let's label a point A on the wire.  A is a distance $l$ away (upward) from point $O$.  Let's move slightly upward from point A and label point B.  Point B is a distance $l+dl$ from point $O$.  The distance between points A and B is $dl$.  Segment AB is the wire element whose magnetic field at point P you are trying to calculate, which is expressed by eqn (i).  Does that help?

Comment: The end goal of this exercise with $l$ and $dl$ is that you have a segment of wire AB, both of whose end points are *exactly the same* distance and direction from point $P$ (for all intents and purposes)

Comment: Let me elaborate my question, how did they conveniently consider the element's length to be dl which also happens to be at a distance l from the point O? There should be a logic behind assuming things, right? Or else all formulas can be derived by assuming stuff conveniently like that. I hope you understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145574/discussion-between-thunderglove-and-rc-23).

Comment: i don't know why you are thinking that $dl$ and $l$ are somehow related. $dl$ is just an integration variable and nothing more -- its sole purpose is to ensure that $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dl$ is $L$.

Comment: I edited my comment for clarity: put another way, $dl$ is not a distance $l$ away from $O$. It is a line element that is defined everywhere, and it just happens that at a distance $l$ from $O$ it has the value that is calculated in the text, because of the geometry and the chain rule.

Comment: r_phys that is a good way to put it

Comment: Wow, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

$l$ is just the position variable for points along the path of the wire. If they changed the symbols to $y$ and $dy$ would it make sense to you?

At any given position $y$ (or $l$) relative to the origin at $O$, there is an element of wire of length $dy$ (or $dl$). Integrate all of these elements of wire and you get the whole wire from $M$ to $N$.

It's not clear why they use $l$ instead of $y$, but maybe in the next example, they're going to make the path of the wire not follow one of the Cartesian axes, and then it will be more usual to use $l$ for the position along the path rather than $y$. Maybe it's because they don't want to introduce the Cartesian coordinates in this problem at all, to show that the solution doesn't depend on any particular coordinate system.